# Power BI - Showing all the values of the column using a table visualization

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, powerbi-desktop

The tab visualization in Power BI is showing me only the distinct values of the columns. Is it possible to present all the data?

[image]

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Do you have any sort of ID that identifies each row? If so, you need to add it to the table or use an index as suggested in @CR7SMS answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this. However there is a workaround by using an index column. The index column can be added from the Edit query section. Once the index column is created added it in the table visualization. If you don't want the users to see the index column, you can hide it by reducing the size of the column. Hope this helps.